# Swift + Xcode: use osascript in Mac App

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, osascript

I want to ask if you can use osascript in swift/xcode when designing a Mac (Sierra) app. So I've basically just built an empty app using Xcode and swift.

I would now like to use osascript to launch another app using osascript (preferred).

So I've linked my button to ViewController.swift file.

```
@IBAction func launchApp(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let path = "/usr/bin/env"
    let arguments = ["osascript -e 'tell app \"iTunes\" to activate'"]
    let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
    task.waitUntilExit()
}
```

But I get this error:

```
 env: osascript -e 'tell app "iTunes" to activate': No such file or directory
```

I've also tried using path as /usr/bin/osascript and bash.

Some guidance on this would be great!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `OSAScript` on Cocoa level, use `NSAppleScript`

```
let script = NSAppleScript(source: "activate application \"iTunes\"")!
var errorDict : NSDictionary?
script.executeAndReturnError(&errorDict)
if errorDict != nil { print(errorDict!) }
```

If the application is sandboxed you need to add appropriate entitlements.